# LLDB: List source code

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, lldb

My single most used `gdb` command is `l` followed by `n` followed by `l -`.

How can I get the same in lldb?

I am *not* satisfied with having to type some line number just to see the code somewhere. I want to see where I am in the code, after dumping a ton of variables out to the terminal. And I used to use `l -` to go back to look at where I am, since subsequent calls to `l` will scroll me down (lldb also does this, but crucially does not respond to `l -`).

Perhaps I am missing something and there is some sort of "mode" i can put it in, which will show the corresponding source location in a separate buffer *all the time*. That would be nice, but I'm not even asking for that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Xcode 4.6, lldb's `l` alias is a simple shortcut for `source list`.

In the top of tree sources, this has been improved to behave more like gdb.  If you look at `source/Interpreter/CommandInterpreter.cpp` over at http://lldb.llvm.org/ you'll see that `l` is now a regular expression command alias with these cases:

```
if (list_regex_cmd_ap->AddRegexCommand("^([0-9]+)[[:space:]]*$", "source list --line %1") &&
    list_regex_cmd_ap->AddRegexCommand("^(.*[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]*$", "source list --file '%1' --line %2") &&
    list_regex_cmd_ap->AddRegexCommand("^\\*?(0x[[:xdigit:]]+)[[:space:]]*$", "source list --address %1") &&
    list_regex_cmd_ap->AddRegexCommand("^-[[:space:]]*$", "source list --reverse") &&
    list_regex_cmd_ap->AddRegexCommand("^-([[:digit:]]+)[[:space:]]*$", "source list --reverse --count %1") &&
    list_regex_cmd_ap->AddRegexCommand("^(.+)$", "source list --name \"%1\"") &&
    list_regex_cmd_ap->AddRegexCommand("^$", "source list"))
```

With these cases, you will get behavior like this:

Show current frame:

```
(lldb) f
#0: 0x0000000100000f2b a.out`main + 27 at a.c:15
   12   
   13   
   14   
-> 15       puts ("hi"); // line 15
   16   
   17       puts ("hi"); // line 17
   18   }
```

show previous ten lines:

```
(lldb) l -
   5    
   6    
   7    
   8    
   9        puts ("hi"); // line 9
   10   
   11
```

You can also use the `stop-line-count-after` and `stop-line-count-before` settings to control how much source context is displayed at frame stops.

Note that you can create your own regular expression command alias in your `~/.lldbinit` file with the same behavior as the top-of-tree lldb's `l`.  See `help command regex` for the syntax and an example.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure why `l -` didn't work for me earlier. It does now.

Comment: I was playing around with a toy source file and I noticed if I used `l` repeatedly to the end of the source file, `l -` didn't seem to go backwards again.  You might have seen that if you were near the end of a source file.

Comment: I see. That is surely an annoying bug but I am glad it works most of the time.

Comment: Upvoted because `f` was the magical lldb command I needed to print the current line we are on in the code.

Answer (score 9):

> LLDB: [How to] List source code

ie: For anyone looking for **"How do I make lldb show which line I am on *again*? (since my recent commands have covered it up)"**, it is simply `f`. Type `f` to see where you are at in the code again.

```
f
```

OR

```
frame select
```

Source: [LLDB: List source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480107/lldb-list-source-code/17484386#17484386)

See also the help menu in `lldb`:

```
help f
```

shows the following:

> ```
> (lldb) help f
>      Select the current stack frame by index from within the current thread (see 
>      'thread backtrace'.)
>
> Syntax: f <cmd-options> [<frame-index>]
>
> Command Options Usage:
>   f [-r <offset>] [<frame-index>]
>
>        -r <offset> ( --relative <offset> )
>             A relative frame index offset from the current frame index.
>      
>      This command takes options and free-form arguments.  If your arguments resemble option 
>      specifiers (i.e., they start with a - or --), you must use ' -- ' between the end of 
>      the command options and the beginning of the arguments.
>
> 'f' is an abbreviation for 'frame select'
> ```

The bottom of that help menu shows that "`f` is an abbreviation for `frame select`".

Note that **in `gdb`**, the equivalent command is simply:

```
f
```

OR

```
frame
```

Comment: Related to this subject, would you know how to stop lldb showing the current frame after each step? I've been digging around for ages with no luck. https://github.com/snare/voltron/issues/286

Comment: @RichieHH, it looks like you figured it out and closed that issue?

Comment: yes. I would have thought that it should be a stop hook but its "hard coded" depending on the values of settings stop-line-count-before and  stop-line-count-after. Setting both to 0 worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
user@hostname> lldb -o "image lookup -rvn file" -o "quit" "Name of exec-file" | grep "CompileUnit"

user@hostname> lldb -o "image lookup -rvs file" -o "quit" "Name of exec-file" | grep "CompileUnit"
```